# Spring data: bulk delete list of entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

How can I bulk delete with Spring JPA having list of *entities*?

The following would work:
`void deleteByIdIn(List<Integer> ids)`

However I do have a list of *entities*, not ids. I could convert the list to the list of ids, but I would prefer not to.

I am looking for something like: `void deleteAll(List<Entitity> entities)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But `CrudRepository` has exactly that method: [deleteAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#deleteAll-java.lang.Iterable-)

And `JpaRepository` has: [deleteInBatch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#deleteInBatch-java.lang.Iterable-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the repo (`Repository` and all inheritors) you use you can call

```
void deleteById(Long id);

void delete(Identity entity);

void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends Identity> entities);

void deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> entities);

void deleteAllInBatch();
```

Or create something like

```
@Query("Delete From Identity i Where i.id In :ids")
void deleteCustom(@Param("ids") Iterable<? extends Long> ids);
```

Answer (score -2):

u need override this Methode: void deleteAll(List entities)

```
 void delete(Entitity entities){
     repo.delete(entities);
 }

void deleteAll(List<Entitity> entities){
   foreach(Entitity entitie:entities){
     delete(entitie);
 }
}
```

Comment: It work, but it's very time consuming, and it have to be transational, so it may cause bdd lock. And by the way, bulk delete already exist in `Spring` `JPA` `Repository`, it useless to build another one.